# Validating ActionErrors in JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, struts

Is is possible to validate or view the ActionErrors/ActionMessages in JavaScript? so that proper javascript alert can be displayed on the screen.

Thanks.

Comment: will you be more specific want u want to acheive?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript used for client-side validations, where as ActionErrors/ActionMessages are for serverside.

Precisely, Struts validation is an alternative to the Javascript validations. So Why would you want to combine both of them? I feel it is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can.

you must add these 2 lines to your jsp file.

```
<script src="scripts/libs/staticStrutsJvs.js"></script>
<html:javascript formName="XXXForm" dynamicJavascript="true" staticJavascript="false" bundle="someBundleName" />
```

File staticStrutsJvs is a part of struts framework.
These lines automatic generate javascript validation code with method names
validateXXXForm()

In the end you have to call this method before submit form.

```
<html:form action="/XXXAction" method="post" onsubmit="return validateXXXForm(this);">
```